# Publish org-mode to HTML using a separate directory for each post

Tags: org-mode, org-export

I want to publish each of my org-mode posts so the HTML output uses a separate folder for each post.  I want to avoid .html in the URL.  I want the posts to look like `http://example.com/my-org-post/` instead of `http://example.com/my-org-post.html`.

Is there a publishing setting to achieve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Okay, this was a little bit involved, but I have a solution now.  There were two main steps:

- Create the appropriate folder in the output directory.  I used the new advice system, inspired by db48x.
- Fix links to point to "example/index.html" instead of "example.html".  I created a new backend, derived from `ox-html.el`.  It was a one-line change.  But the change was inside a lambda within a function meaning I couldn't modify the lambda even with advice.

I made a quick project at https://github.com/jschaf/org-export-html-clean

Answer (score 4):

There's no way to just configure this, but you can modify the behavior without too much work if you want.

There's a function called `org-export-output-file-name` which computes the file name for the export. You can write a modification for this function using `defadvice`.

I've not tested it specifically, but something like this may get you started:

```
(defadvice org-export-output-file-name (around export-to-directories activate)
  "alters the org export process to create a subdirectory for each exported org file"
  (let* ((visited-file (buffer-file-name (buffer-base-buffer)))
         (dir-name (file-name-sans-extension (file-name-nondirectory visited-file))))
    (setf pub-dir
          (concat (file-name-as-directory (or pub-dir "."))
                  dir-name))
    ad-do-it))
```

`org-export-output-file-name` takes an argument called `pub-dir` which contains the directory to publish to; this is generally taken from your project configuration. This advice sets `pub-dir` to a new value before calling `ad-do-it` to call the original function.

Of course, even if I haven't made any other mistakes, there's still one potential problem here. The original `org-export-output-file-name` is still going to use the current file name again when constructing the output file name. For example, when exporting the file `foo.org` this advised function is going to return the file name `./foo/foo.html`. For your use-case, it sounds like a better value would be `./foo/index.html`.

If the code had been written to pass the file name in as an argument this would be easy to fix; just override that argument. It seems to me that the only way to fix this is to modify the return value as well as the arguments:

```
(defadvice org-export-output-file-name (around export-to-directories activate)
  "alters the org export process to create a subdirectory for each exported org file"
  (let* ((visited-file (buffer-file-name (buffer-base-buffer)))
         (dir-name (file-name-sans-extension (file-name-nondirectory visited-file))))
    (setf pub-dir
          (concat (file-name-as-directory (or pub-dir "."))
                  dir-name))
    ad-do-it
    (setf ad-return-value
          (replace-regexp-in-string (regexp-quote (concat dir-name "." extension))
                                    (concat "index." extension)
                                    ad-return-value))))
```

It's also possible that you could handle that with a rewrite rule (or similar) in your web server config.

Comment: This is pretty close, but causes  the error "Output file not writable", probably because the directory doesn't exist.  I'm looking at advising org-html-publish-to-html.

Comment: Good point. You could throw a call to `make-directory`.